# How to use histeq function on color Image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I have a color image. I need to apply **Histogram equalization** in that.

If I use it on the following code

```
im = imread('E:\S1\New\Image1.png');
Test = histeq(im);
```

I get the following error

```
Function HISTEQ expected its first input, I, to be two-dimensional.

Error in ==> histeq at 71
iptcheckinput(a,{'uint8','uint16','double','int16','single'}, ...
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most common solution is to convert the image to an [HSV colour space](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) and then apply `histeq` only to the `V` (i.e. value or intensity) channel.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Histogram_equalization_of_color_images

Comment: @Addee https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html

Comment: Actually, I want to use hyperspectral images for histogram equalization. do you think applying histogram equalization separately on each band will be same as applying as whole?

Comment: @addee equalisation is basically just to make the image easier for humans to interpret. So you can try equalise each band or just the value band and see what makes more sense. However if the colours are meaningful then you'll need to be careful to preserve the meaning. You'll probably still be better off just equalising the value channel as you'll want to preserve hue.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is histogram is only well defined for gray-scale images. How would you define histogram equlization for colors?
Hist-eq tries to re-distribute the gray values to span (as evenly as possible) the entire range of 0..255 by slightly changing the brightness of pixels.
If you wish to do the same for colors: that is to fill evenly the entire RGB cube you'll find yourself **changing the colors of pixels**. That is, you'll end up with yellow pixels turning brown.

You'll have to clearly define what you are after.

If you only want to span the entire range of intensities (without affecting the colors), you'll find [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162346/1714410)'s solution very useful.

If you do want to "fill" the entire RGB cube, you might want to consider applying `hiseq` to each channel of the image independently:

```
for ci = 1:size(im,3)
    Test(:,:,ci) = histeq( im(:,:,ci) );
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple way, try this :

```
im = imread('E:\S1\New\Image1.png');
Test =im(:,:,1); ir=histeq(ir); figure; imshow(ir, 'Border', 'tight');
```